# display image in div and rotate in every 5 sec

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am required to design basic image slider using jquery that show images in div of width (312px X 214px). when page loads, a cycle of showing images continuous; sliding from left to right in every 5 sec.

In function FeaturedPropertyImgSlider, i can slide div to left with jquery animation but only once.????

many thanks in advace

### HTML

```
<div class="highlight_Block" id="FeaturesList_block">
     <div id="img_wrapper_05">
          <ul id="FeaturesList_Ul">

           <li id="DEMO1_000001" class="FeaturesList_li">
              <img src="/photos/demo1-000001-p-w-1.jpg" height="214" width="321">
           </li>

           <li id="DEMO1_000002" class="FeaturesList_li">
              <img src="/photos/demo1-000001-p-w-2.jpg" height="214" width="321">
           </li>

           <li id="DEMO1_000003" class="FeaturesList_li">
              <img src="/photos/demo1-000001-p-w-3.jpg" height="214" width="321">
           </li>

          </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$("#FeaturesList_Ul").append("<li id=" + featured_prop.prop_list[index] + " class='FeaturesList_li'><img src='" + featured_prop.prop_img_url[index] + "' height='214' width='321' /></li>");
```

### Call function to run slider

```
setInterval(function () {

      var xyPosition_05 = $("#img_wrapper_05").position();

      var next_X_Position = xyPosition_05.left + 321;

      next_X_Position = '-' + next_X_Position + 'px'

      $("#img_wrapper_05").animate({ left: next_X_Position }, 1000);

},5000);
```

### CSS

```
#FeaturesList_Ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.FeaturesList_li{
  display:inline-block;
}

#img_wrapper_05 {
   width:auto;
   height:214px;
   position:absolute;
   background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: in function FeaturedPropertyImgSlider() i have tried with click event but i want to do process itself when pages loads ... i can't find answer yet!

Comment: A simple google search for "execute javascript on page load" will tell you

Answer (score 0):

The problem of producing sliders is more complex than you  may have realized. For such a simple task, unless you have great jQuery skills, writing it from scratch is overkill. I recommend the cycle plugin

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Checkout "scroll left" I believe that is what you want:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html

---

then it should be something like

```
$('#FeaturesList_Ul').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollLeft', 
    speed:    300, 
    timeout:  2000 
});
```

you may have to alter your css a bit. Good luck!

Comment: I have figure out.. i have put images in li tag with css property inline (horizontal) and put the ul in div "#img_wrapper_05" with width:auto; and put this div another div highlight_Block with width:312px that size of image and overflow hidden. now all i need to animate #img_wrapper_05" left:312px with every 5 sec. my animation works but only once.

Comment: Right, you need to cycle it back to the beginning, and not be a super fast slide back to the beginning, but rather have the first image slide in from the right. That is not a problem solved by your method.

Comment: ultimately for your method to work, you will need to make a second `#img_wrapper` that you can swap with for that critical transition from the last slide to the first slide, or you can use a plugin and do the same thing with no work.

Comment: i have edit setInterval function above, my problem is, it animates only once. once this problem sorted, i can count total number li tags and put counter in interval and in if condition check the number of animation == number of li tags... once condition get true, i will set counter to 0 and put #img_wrapper_05 in original position

Comment: i know this animation is working http://jsfiddle.net/3GHaf/ so i must be doing something wrong that stoping setInterval function???

Comment: Can you post the real code then? In your example you are not checking for an end condition.

Comment: no i haven't reach to that stage, i am still trying to figure out, why my animation is working once only!!!!

Comment: @toxic your animation is working only once because its not magic. Its html moving to the left, when it gets to the last image its moved all the way to the left like a piece of paper. You need a second one to swap with. This should be obvious.